# Asp.net Core 2.0 external authentication not persisting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net Core 2.0 with various external authentications (Google, Twitter, etc).

Everything is working, and I get a validated response back with the OnTicketReceived event, however, all subsequent calls to the site do not persist the user.

Here is my startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
        {
            googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Google:ClientId"];
            googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Google:ClientSecret"];
            googleOptions.CallbackPath = "/auth/google";
            googleOptions.SaveTokens = true;
            googleOptions.Events = new OAuthEvents {OnTicketReceived = async e => await HandleOnTicketReceived(authService, e),};
        })
        .AddTwitter(twitterOptions =>
        {
            twitterOptions.ConsumerKey = Configuration["Twitter:ClientId"];
            twitterOptions.ConsumerSecret = Configuration["Twitter:ClientSecret"];
            twitterOptions.CallbackPath = "/auth/twitter";
            twitterOptions.RetrieveUserDetails = true;
            twitterOptions.SaveTokens = true;
            twitterOptions.Events = new TwitterEvents {OnTicketReceived = async e => await HandleOnTicketReceived(authService, e),};
        });

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

This all seems to work great. I get all the necessary data from each OAuth provider. Here is an example:
[properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s7ZI.png)

```
private async Task HandleOnTicketReceived(IAuthService authService, TicketReceivedContext e)
{
    var identity = e.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    // HERE identity is correct for all external auth providers, so it is working this far
}
```

The problem is every subsequent call to the site has lost the user's external identity. What was there is now gone.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

    // HERE is the problem -- on all subsequent calls, identity is basically empty

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

How can I get the user identity to persist across calls? The cookie "Identity.External" is set and seems correct.

Edit:

I have also added a sql backend with

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

and

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
```

The AspNet user tables are created but never populated. I am at a loss for what is missing here.

I should clarify that i am using dbContext.Database.Migrate() to create the authentication tables, so I have confidence the ApplicationDbContext is working. However, there is no error thrown, the tables just don't get populated and subsequent calls just don't get the user's identity set.

Comment: Do you have any data in your tokens?

Comment: Yes, I get everything I expect in the OnTicketReceived. Claims like "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" etc. They disappear on subsequent calls though. I would expect the cookie Identity.External (which contains some identifier) to allow the content to persist, but it does not.